# how to add ionic custom directives to react js?

Tags: ionic-framework, reactjs

I am working on react js and would like to add ionic directives inside the react js code. can i do that?

For example: `<ion-list>` - Ionic directive

I want to add `<ion-list>` inside the react js. please help me on this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that in JSX: `return (<ion-list />);`  What is the problem?

Comment: I tried that but no luck. can you please give me simple example?

Comment: Could you edit your question and add a more complete example of what you're trying to do and what's specifically not working?

Answer (score 0):

No. `<ion-list>` is a angularJS directive and will not work directly in React. You have to create a similar ReactJS component for the same. You have to look into the Ionic source code for this directive and create the same by picking up the html/css and the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a large part of the Ionic functionality in React (and still working on the remaining components). I have open sourced it, have a look here: [React-Ionic](https://github.com/pors/reactionic)